# Django tabular inline display

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

Is it possible to change the display of inlines in order to change it to [this](https://creately.com/diagram/h0gjalof1/YZluiXwm7BlpygwNW6j4MvNDJN8=)? I was thinking of changing the admin template file "tabular.html", is it going to be possible or should I change something else?

**Update**

Ok, I've been trying to edit the tabular.html but my experience with Django isn't enough to understand how/where to make the necessary changes... Any clue of where I should start?
Shouldn't I be changing the CSS also?
I guess that {{ field.field }} automatically renders the dropdown menu (Django admin default) if I'm understand this correctly...

**Update 2**

I was able to change the second column to the functionality that I wanted but I think that for the first one it's going to be trickier... Current [status](http://img684.imageshack.us/img684/9548/screenshot20120401at104.png)

**Update 3**

One hack that I think would work is to display on each of the inlines only one of the options of the first field and then deactivate the "add another option". How can I iterate on the options in "tabular.html" ?

**Update 4**

I guess the trick should be done here... How can I iterate on the field choices in order to display only one choice per line?

```
{% for fieldset in inline_admin_form %}
          {% for line in fieldset %}
            {% for field in line %}
            {{ field.get_choices_display }}
              <td class="{{ field.field.name }}">
              {% if field.is_readonly %}
                  <p>{{ field.contents }}</p>
              {% else %}
                  {{ field.field.errors.as_ul }}
                  {{ field.field }}
              {% endif %}
              </td>
            {% endfor %}
          {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you could change `template` of your InlineModelAdmin instance to your customized template, for example `customized_inline.html`. Simply copy django/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/edit_inline/tabular.html to customized_inline.html in your template path as starting.

***edit***

Perhaps I was misunderstanding. If you want to change the rendering style of a form field, the normal way is to change its [widget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/). In Django ModelAdmin and InlineModelAdmin, the main ways of customizing a field widget goes around `BaseModelAdmin.formfield_for_dbfield` method inside `django/contrib/admin/options.py`, reading the code and [the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/) when you want to change the widget of a form field.

For field having choices, you could simply set [radio_fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.radio_fields) in ModelAdmin/InlineModelAdmin instance to render the field as radio select instead of dropdown.

Furthermore, use OneToOneField instead of ForeignKey, or set `extra` and `max_num` in your InlineModelAdmin instance to prevent admin from rendering multiple rows of inline, like:

```
class SomeInlineAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Foo
    extra = 1
    max_num = 1
```

I cannot open your second link, you could post things in the question instead of using a external link.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to get the effect that I wanted.